# Let ${a_n}$ be the sequence of positive integers defined by $a_1=1$, $a_2=3$, $a_{n+2}=(n+3)a_{n+1} - (n+2)a_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, divisibility

Let ${a_n}$ be the sequence of positive integers defined by
$a_1=1$, $a_2=3$, $a_{n+2}=(n+3)a_{n+1} -(n+2)a_n$.
Find all positive integers $n$ such that 11 | $a_n$.

So my thought process so far is that I need to show that both $(n+3)a_{n+1}$ and $(n+2)a_n$ at a certain point are both divisible by 11.

$a_3 = 6*3-5*1$,
$a_4 = 7*(6*3-5*1)-6*3$,
$a_5 = 8*(7*(6*3-5*1)-6*3)- 7*(6*3-5*1)$
...
$a_9 = 12*(11*(...) - 11*(...)$...

So evidently at $a_9$, both $(n+3)a_{n+1}$ and $(n+2)a_n$ are divisible by 11, so for all $n>=9$m, the property holds? My question would be if there is a more efficient way to do and if I'm missing any other values?

Comment: Your method seems fine. For more, pls see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205873/find-all-n-in-n-such-that-11-a-n-with-the-following-sequence-defined

Comment: Not only I did not find any $n$ such that $11|a(n)$, but for $8\le n\le 30$ I got all numbers congruent to $3$ mod $11$

Comment: @Raffaele If that is true it is easy enough to prove by induction.

Comment: First $a+b$ can be divisible by $11$ even if $a$ and $b$ aren't. Then in $a_9$ the thing multiplied by $12$ is $a_8=11\times [ ]- 10\times [ ]$ and isn't obviously divisible by $11$. Then you should probably start by computing a few small values (note you can reduce modulo $11$ to simplify the arithmetic) to see what happens and if a pattern emerges.

Comment: @MarkBennet OP has done mistakes. $a_9$ is divisible by $13$ not by $11$

Comment: $a_3 = 4*3 - 3*1 =9, a_4 = 5*9 - 4*3 = 33$. Note that $a_n = (n+1)a_{n-1} - na_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, if both $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are divisible by $11$, then so is $a_{n+2}$. Thus if you find an index $n$ such that $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are divisible by $11$, then all $a_m$ with $m \ge n$ are divisible by $11$.

An easy compution shows that up to $n = 11$ precisely $a_4, a_8, a_{10}, a_{11}$ are divisible by $11$. This answers your question.

Note that it suffices to *explicitly* compute $a_n$ up to $n = 8$. We have $a_8 = 46233 = 11*4203$. Since $a_7 = 5913$ is not divisible by $11$, also $a_9 = 10*a_8 + 9*a_7$ is not divisible by $11$. But $a_{10} = 11*a_9 + 10*a_8$ and thus $a_{11} = 12*a_{10} + 11*a_9$ are.

Comment: This is incorrect. Remainders of division by 11 are $\{1,3,2,7,9,3,4,3,3,3,3\}$ for the first $11$ elements of the sequence

Comment: @Raffaele $a_3 = 9, a_4 = 33$. The OP's computations are wrong.

Comment: Remainders mod $11$ are $1,3,9,0,10,4,6,0,1,0,0, \ldots$